# Xcode 14 Storyboard, segue push forces Modal?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue, xcode14

I am developing in Xcode 14 with Storyboards. I have set up several ViewControllers and when I add segues, the views become Modal and have a gap at the top. This is not what I want. I've tried each of the segue types and none of them allow the 2nd VC to present full-screen. Before and After screenshots below. How does one now use segues to push VCs without them looking like modals?

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode changed the default style years ago.
To allow the 2nd VC to present full-screen:

**In Xcode IDE**, select segue, change its `Kind` to `Present Modally` and the `presentation style` to `Full Screen`.
[image]

**In Swift Code**, you can assign viewcontroller's `modalPresentationStyle` to `.fullScreen`

Comment: Thank you! It's been a few years since Ive done this, works perfectly!